# Bundler not targeting working directories gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, bundler

I'm working on several RoR projects. Somehow the BUNDLE_GEMFILE environmental variable got set to one specific project's gemfile and now whenever I `bundle` it only compiles the libraries in that project.
Running `bundle config` gives me

Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.

gemfile

`Set via BUNDLE_GEMFILE: "/Path/To/Project/That/All/Bundles/Are/Going/To"
Set for the current user (/Users/RoccoBasso/.bundle/config): "/Path/To/Another/Project"`

I've been working around it by setting the BUNDLE_GEMFILE to whichever project I'm working on with `export BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Path/To/Current/Projects/Gemfile`, but that only works for one terminal window at a time. How can I set/reset bundler so it will target the gemfile of whatever project I'm in?

Comment: Try removing the path set to BUNDLE_GEMFILE. By default, bundler will search up from the current working directory until it finds a Gemfile.

Comment: How would I do that? I don't see any reference to it in either my .bash_profile or my .zshrc (using oh-my-zsh)

Comment: What displays when you type `bundle install gemfile` in the command line?

Comment: Throws an error: ERROR: "bundle install" was called with arguments ["gemfile"]
Usage: "bundle install [OPTIONS]"

Comment: According to the Bundler site, Bundler retrieves its configuration from the local application (`app/.bundle/config`), environment variables, and the user's home directory (`~/.bundle/config`), in that order of priority. I'd check your directories' config file and see if a path has been set to BUNDLE_GEMFILE. If so, I'd remove it so it resets back to the default.